# How do I check if an embedded resource exists or not?

Tags: delphi, validation, embedded-resource

In Delphi, I'm building an HTTP Application, or a Web Server rather. It's essentially an entire website built into a single EXE file. The files I'm embedding include HTML, JS, CSS, SWF, PNG, XML, etc. The resource names are the same as the original filename, with the `.` replaced with an `_`. In the end, there will be somewhere around 40-60 files embedded inside the EXE.

The problem is I don't want to write code wrapping each and every individual file. Right now, I am declaring a constant for each resource, and using that constant when acquiring the resource using `TResourceStream`. The HTTP request is asking for any particular file, and since I'll have a bunch of files, I don't want a separate way of handling each file. Plus, in the future, when I add a new file to be embedded, all I should have to do is add it to my Resource Script (.rc). So I decided to change my mechanism to automatically resolve the filename requested to the name of the resource. For example, `/Home.HTML` gets resolved to `HOME_HTML` which is supposed to be the name of the embedded resource. I need to check if such a resource exists before loading it.

I could *try* to load it and catch any *exception* but this would produce errors in debug if the resource doesn't exist. How would I go about performing such a check without using `try..except`?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  One of the major advantages of having a web server that reads *from the file system* is that you can change the content on your site without having to change the server itself.  Right now, if you need to change a file or add a new file, you'll have to build a new server, take the existing one down, copy the new one in, and restart it.  That looks bad, even if the downtime's relatively short...

Comment: @MasonWheeler I actually do have hundreds, in fact almost a thousand other files which the app will generate dynamically. The stuff that is embedded is just the critical stuff which will never change. The above description was just a sample. The reason I'm doing this is for distribution. The goal is to be able to send just this single EXE to someone and have them immediately be able to run it.

Comment: May I get an explanation for the downvote please? Or is it just one of the usual Delphi haters?

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me, so have a free upvote.

Comment: @Jerry: Ah, I see.  OK, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, something like

```
if(FindResource(hInstance, PChar(ResourceName), RT_RCDATA) <> 0)then begin
   // load the resource
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Win32 API `FindResource()` function.