# delphi 2006 - Is it possible to find out if a resource name exists?

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, delphi-2006

What it the best way to find out if a resource name exists - other than seeing if

```
LoadFromResourceName (HInstance, 'FOOBAR')
```

causes an exception?

Comment: This is a duplicate and has been asked many times before. For example [How do I check if an embedded resource exists or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744979/how-do-i-check-if-an-embedded-resource-exists-or-not)

Comment: @David That's what I figured, but I would have expected those solutions to be served up as I was entering my question (Delphi's help for `LoadFromResourceName` wasn't much help either, but it never is.  They seemed to have abandoned to idea of hyperlinks to other related useful topics in D2006).

Comment: SO search is notoriously flaky. I found the dupe with a google search. But I also searched on `FindResource`. It's easy to find dupes once you know the answer! No worries!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an embedded resource exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744979/how-do-i-check-if-an-embedded-resource-exists-or-not)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (remember pass the proper resource type)

```
 if FindResource(hInstance, 'FOOBAR', RT_RCDATA) <> 0 then
  // do something
```